# PayPal IPN Sandbox Not Returning

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am looking to implement PayPals IPN via a php page in codeigniter. When I test my code with the sandbox, I receive no response from Paypal. This is despite my program receiving the original message and the ipn simulators stating that "IPN was sent and the handshake was verified.". Can anyone point out what is wrong in the following code:

```
if(array_key_exists('test_ipn', $_POST) && 1 == (int) $_POST['test_ipn'])
        $url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    else
        $url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

    // Set up request to PayPal
    $request = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($request, array
    (
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array_merge(array('cmd' => '_notify-validate'),$_POST)),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
    ));

    // Execute request and get response and status code
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    $status   = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    // Close connection
    curl_close($request);

    $myfile = fopen("/var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/apidev/httpdocs/application/controllers/test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, json_encode($_POST)."\n\n");
    fwrite($myfile, $url."\n\n");
    //$response = file_get_contents($url);
    fwrite($myfile, "Response: ".$response."\n");
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

The contents of the file are:

```
{"payment_type":"instant","payment_date":"Tue Mar 29 2016 08:35:27 GMT-0400 (EDT)","payment_status":"Completed","address_status":"confirmed","payer_status":"verified","first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","payer_email":"buyer@paypalsandbox.com","payer_id":"TESTBUYERID01","address_name":"John Smith","address_country":"United States","address_country_code":"US","address_zip":"95131","address_state":"CA","address_city":"San Jose","address_street":"123 any street","business":"seller@paypalsandbox.com","receiver_email":"seller@paypalsandbox.com","receiver_id":"seller@paypalsandbox.com","residence_country":"US","item_name1":"something","item_number1":"AK-1234","tax":"2.02","mc_currency":"USD","mc_fee":"0.44","mc_gross":"12.34","mc_gross_1":"12.34","mc_handling":"2.06","mc_handling1":"1.67","mc_shipping":"3.02","mc_shipping1":"1.02","txn_type":"cart","txn_id":"366657134","notify_version":"2.1","custom":"xyz123","invoice":"abc1234","test_ipn":"1","verify_sign":"AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31Ad3zyAU11sBY.hh-lw41XA9TQLb4"}

https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Response:
```

Comment: Have you set up notify_url ?

Comment: Yea, but it is to our production code, not the dev code where this is running.

Comment: To get response in dev code you have to mention that path too.

Comment: Can I input a separate one for dev, or do I need to constantly swap them out? I only see a place for a single one.

Comment: Ideally, you should keep its value in a variable which will content two different values for dev and production environments.